# How can I display users a, b, and c with their corresponding sum of money using group by and sum in MySQL join?

Tags: mysql, join, sum, group

```
mysql> select * from bills;
+----+------+-------+---------------------+---------------------+
| id | user | money | created_at          | updated_at          |
+----+------+-------+---------------------+---------------------+
|  1 | a    |   100 | 2023-05-20 23:15:53 | 2023-05-20 23:15:53 |
|  2 | b    |   200 | 2023-05-20 23:16:01 | 2023-05-20 23:16:01 |
+----+------+-------+---------------------+---------------------+
2 rows in set (0.00 sec)

mysql> select * from enroles;
+----+------+-------+---------------------+---------------------+
| id | user | money | created_at          | updated_at          |
+----+------+-------+---------------------+---------------------+
|  1 | b    |   300 | 2023-05-20 23:16:18 | 2023-05-20 23:16:18 |
|  2 | c    |   400 | 2023-05-20 23:16:24 | 2023-05-20 23:16:24 |
+----+------+-------+---------------------+---------------------+
2 rows in set (0.00 sec)
```

How to show user a,b,c and sum(money)?

I try group by and sum(), but failed...

Who can help me? thanks.

Comment: Append your SQL attempt to the question, so that we know the attempt, and where you might not have the correct info.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to retrieve the total money from both tables per user, use `UNION ALL` to combine the result set of both `SELECT` statements, then apply `GROUP BY` and `SUM()` to get the intended output:

```
select `user`, sum(money) as total
from (
  select `user`, money
  from bills
  union all
  select `user`, money
  from enroles
) as s
group by `user`
```

Comment: Very Thanks ^_^

| user | total |
+----+------+
| a    |   100 |
| b    |   500 |
| c    |   400 |